# Import huge data-set from SQL server to HDF5

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

I am trying to import ~12 Million records with 8 columns into Python.Because of its huge size my laptop memory would not be sufficient for this. Now I'm trying to import the SQL data into a HDF5 file format. It would be very helpful if someone can share a snippet of code that queries data from SQL and saves it in the HDF5 format in chunks.I am open to use any other file format that would be easier to use.

I plan to do some basic exploratory analysis and later on might create some decision trees/Liner regression models using pandas.

```
import pyodbc 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

con = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes',
                     driver = '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}',
                     server = 'SQL_ServerName')
df = pd.read_sql("select * from table_a",con,index_col=['Accountid'],chunksize=1000)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
sql_reader = pd.read_sql("select * from table_a", con, chunksize=10**5)

hdf_fn = '/path/to/result.h5'
hdf_key = 'my_huge_df'
store = pd.HDFStore(hdf_fn)
cols_to_index = [<LIST OF COLUMNS THAT WE WANT TO INDEX in HDF5 FILE>]

for chunk in sql_reader:
     store.append(hdf_key, chunk, data_columns=cols_to_index, index=False)

# index data columns in HDFStore
store.create_table_index(hdf_key, columns=cols_to_index, optlevel=9, kind='full')
store.close()
```

Comment: @user3510503, glad it helps :)

Comment: Guys this code is taking ages for my loading issue. Is there a way to further speed up this process? Thank you!

Comment: @Mike_H, i think first you have to find out what is the bottleneck in your case...

Comment: Bottleneck is memory. 8GB. @MaxU Or do you mean which part of the code block is running the longest time?

Comment: @Mike_H, yep, I mean the slowest part of your code... It might be reading from the DB or saving chunks to HDF5...